# How to sum up from parallel vectors in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors, one with the (floating-point) labels, one with the values, e.g

```
x = c(100.5, 101, 100.5, 102, 99.9, 101, 100.5)
y = c(    3,   1,     1,   2,    0,   1,     0)
```

The result I'm looking for is the sum for each of the labels, i.e.

```
res = list("100.5" = 3+1, "101" = 1+1, "102" = 2)
```

(Ideally "99.9" is not there, as shown above; but if it is there with a count of zero that is also acceptable.)

None of the R idioms I know seem to work, so I tried a C++ style loop: use a `for` loop to iterate through `y`, grab the value from `x`, but then I get stuck on the "does the value already exist in `res`" part (to know whether to initialize a new element, or add on to the existing entry). And it just feels so wrong to be doing it this way in R!

**By The Way**

It needn't be a `list`; a named vector, or class `table`, are also fine. (If it was C++ I'd be using `std::map<double,double>`.) One of the things I need to do next is be able to merge them, and named vectors, at least, go wrong:

```
res1 = c(3,4,5);names(res1) = c("100.5","101","102")
res2 = c(2,4,6);names(res2) = c("99.5", "100.5", "102")
res3 = c(2,7,4,11);names(res3) = c("99.5", "100.5", "101", "102")
res1 + res2
```

`res1 + res2` does not give me `res3`. Doing the same thing with `list` objects gives "non-numeric argument to binary operator". (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897398/841830 shows how to sum `table` objects together; a similar approach might work for named vectors...)

Comment: `tapply(y, INDEX = as.factor(x), sum)`

Comment: And, re your *By the Way*, if you want to be merging things, use data frames. Start with `res1 = data.frame(values = 3:5, labels = c("100.5","101","102"))`, etc., then use `merge` to merge them. `+` does addition, `merge` does merging.

Answer (score 3):

Base R has a family of *apply* functions you can read [lots about here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/903061). Reading through that (and wanting to stay in base R), `tapply` is what you're looking for, it applies a function based on a grouping and condenses the result.

```
x = c(100.5, 101, 100.5, 102, 99.9, 101, 100.5)
y = c(    3,   1,     1,   2,    0,   1,     0)
tapply(y, INDEX = as.factor(x), sum)
#  99.9 100.5   101   102 
#     0     4     2     2
```

You can also use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(y, by = list(x), FUN = sum)
#   Group.1 x
# 1    99.9 0
# 2   100.5 4
# 3   101.0 2
# 4   102.0 2
```

As for your other issues, I'd strongly recommend using data frames rather than trying to do too much with named vectors. There's a lot of infrastructure for working with data frames (in Base R, `merge`, `aggregate` and many others; also the `data.table` and `dplyr` packages).

As another note, using floats as labels is risky... I'd keep them as `character` or `factor` classes as much as possible to avoid bugs caused by with floating point precision.

Answer (score 2):

We could also use `xtabs`.  By default, it gets the `sum`

```
xtabs(y~x)
#x
# 99.9 100.5   101   102 
#    0     4     2     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
x = c(100.5, 101, 100.5, 102, 99.9, 101, 100.5)
y = c(    3,   1,     1,   2,    0,   1,     0)

df <- data.frame(x1=as.character(x),x2=y,stringsAsFactors=F)

keys <- unique(df$x1)
vals <- sapply(keys,function (x) sum(df[x==df$x1,]$x2))
vals
```

yielding

```
100.5   101   102  99.9 
    4     2     2     0
```

Comment: Because I didn't think of it. You are simply better at this :)

Comment: I've just spent too much time on SO... [third most-upvoted R question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/903061)

Comment: Anyway, post it. It is the best answer.